# How to disable auto-p in WordPress?

Tags: wp-autop

I need to remove the "wpautop filter" from my WordPress Website because it is adding too many paragraphs. I'm new to WordPress. I don't know how to create Child themes. The name of my theme is the "supreme directory". is it also possible to remove the "wpautop filter" from the supreme directory theme directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Line Breaks From Cell Content in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339349/remove-line-breaks-from-cell-content-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 2):

In your child theme's `functions.php`, try something like this:

```php
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wp_autop' );
```

Note that this may have unintended side-effects, and will definitely have an effect on how your content renders.

Comment: there is no underscore in wp_autop. remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');